# Run time Complexity

Tags: runtime, time-complexity, big-o

I believe that the following code is big theta of n^3, is this correct?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
{  // A is an array of integers
   if (A[i] == 0) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
          if (A[i] == 0) {
             for (int k = 0; k <= j; k++) {
                 A[i] = 1; 
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

And that the following is big theta of nlog(n)

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
{
   func(i);
}

void func(int x) {
  if (x <= 1) return;
  func(x-1);
}
```

because the for loop would run log(n) times, and func runs at most n recursive calls.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition looks correct. Note that for the first bit if the input contains non-zero elements the time complexity drops down to big-theta(n). If you remove the checks it would definitely be big-theta(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the second snippet, however the first is not `Big-Theta(n^3)`. It is not even `O(n^3)`! The key observation is: **for each i, the innermost loop will execute at most once**.

Obviously, the worst-case is when the array contains only zeros. However, `A[i]` will be set to 1 in the first pass of the inner-most loop, and all subsequent checks of `if (A[i] == 0)` for the same `i` will be evaluated to false and the innermost loop will not be executed anymore until `i` increments. Therefore, there are total of `1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n = n * (n + 1) / 2` iterations, so the time complexity of the first snippet is `O(n^2)`.

Hope this helps!